# Get a List from a Binary Tree, TypeError

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, typeerror

So with this function I'm trying to traverse a binary tree (in order) and output the values in the tree instead as a list.

With this code I get a "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list" on the 14th line (although the problem originates on the 6th line) and I'm not sure why that is.

Any help people can offer would be much appreciated.

```
def getList(bST):
    wholeList = []
    if bST is None:
        print []
    if bST ['left']:
        leftList = getList(bST['left'])
    else:
        leftList = []
    rootList = [bST['data']]
    if bST ['right']:
        rightList = getList(bST['right'])
    else:
        rightList = []
    wholeList = leftList + rootList + rightList
    print wholeList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `return wholeList` at the end. As a result, `getList()` returns None.

Comment: sigh... sometimes I'm dumb.